# Different browsers return different widths

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm blown away. I'm trying to establish a breakpoint for responsive commands and when testing the browsers window width or even an image width I'm getting accurate returns from Chrome and results that are way off by firefox and IE.

Visit this page: http://sta.manageorsell.com/breakpoint.php with both Chrome and either firefox or IE.

You will see my point.  I've totally simplified the source code.  I've even added a setInterval to insure it had nothing to do with elements not being loaded yet.

I'm stupified...

In todays responsive world a browser compatible method for testing the viewport / window width has to be among the most common needs for developers

What sayeth the group ?

Jay
CompuMatter

Comment: I'm getting the same values in Chrome 32, Firefox 27 and IE11. How do they differ when you try it out? And how do you know that Chrome is the one that measures correctly in your case?

Comment: UPDATE:  I just tried it from a different computer and it works normally.  How strange, it is something within my own computer that seems to be causing these different browsers to offer different settings.  However, on another computer in my shop they were both accurate and the same.

I doubt anyone's going to know why that one is. It's quite obscure.

I know that Chrome is the correct one because I'm on a 1920w monitor and it gets quite close to that.  The other browsers are in the 1520w range.

Answer (score 0):

I think your are fooled be the good old IE quirks mode trap :-)
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quirks_mode

You have not defined at DOCTYPE for your page, which will sent IE into quirks mode, which will simulate IE6, which uses another box-model then the others.
IE6 uses border-box as box-model and the others uses content-box as box-model.
See this post about the box-model: http://css-tricks.com/the-css-box-model/

Try adding a DOCTYPE to your page, I would suggest the HTML 5 doctype:

As an extra service info, I just tried out your sample in Chrome 29, Firefox 23 and IE 11, which all return the same widths.